# Pandas groupby two columns and create a new column based on difference in days from third column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with creation_timestamps and personal_id's. Each personal_id has one or more application_id's. An application_id can have a bunch of rows, but they all have the same creation_timestamp.

I want to create a column that indicates the days between two application_id's for a given personal_id. All the offer rows within the application_id should show the same days between the two application_id's.

Here's the code I've tried to modify in a bunch of ways:

```
# Calculate days between consecutive applications for each personal_id
df['days_between_applications'] = (
    df.groupby(['personal_id'])['creation_timestamp']
    .diff()
    .dt.days
)
```

Here's a preview of the current result:

|  | personal_id | application_id | creation_timestamp | days_between_applications |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1007 | c1de3552cfb0 | e18e5d77199f | 2019-05-16 06:53:57.817842 | NaN |
| 1008 | c1de3552cfb0 | e18e5d77199f | 2019-05-16 06:53:57.817842 | 0.0 |
| 1010 | c1de3552cfb0 | e18e5d77199f | 2019-05-16 06:53:57.817842 | 0.0 |
| 1006 | c1de3552cfb0 | e18e5d77199f | 2019-05-16 06:53:57.817842 | 0.0 |
| 7094153 | c1de3552cfb0 | 1f64dd61aee2 | 2023-08-07 11:01:45.588173 | 1533.0 |
| 7094147 | c1de3552cfb0 | 1f64dd61aee2 | 2023-08-07 11:01:45.588173 | 0.0 |

This is what I'm trying to achieve:

|  | personal_id | application_id | creation_timestamp | days_between_applications |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1007 | c1de3552cfb0 | e18e5d77199f | 2019-05-16 06:53:57.817842 | NaN |
| 1008 | c1de3552cfb0 | e18e5d77199f | 2019-05-16 06:53:57.817842 | NaN |
| 1010 | c1de3552cfb0 | e18e5d77199f | 2019-05-16 06:53:57.817842 | NaN |
| 1006 | c1de3552cfb0 | e18e5d77199f | 2019-05-16 06:53:57.817842 | NaN |
| 7094153 | c1de3552cfb0 | 1f64dd61aee2 | 2023-08-07 11:01:45.588173 | 1533.0 |
| 7094147 | c1de3552cfb0 | 1f64dd61aee2 | 2023-08-07 11:01:45.588173 | 1533.0 |

I've tried to forward fill, sort and then forward fill, groupby personal_id and application_id etc, but nothing has worked.

Comment: In my solution below, I'm assuming the application_id are unique (i.e. two different personal_id cannot have the same application_id). If this is not the case, please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could [`drop_duplicates`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) then compute the diff between successive applications per personal_id with [`groupby.diff`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.diff.html). Finally, [`map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) this to the original DataFrame:

```
df['creation_timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['creation_timestamp'])

diff = (df
   .drop_duplicates(['personal_id', 'application_id'])
   .sort_values(by='creation_timestamp')
   .set_index('application_id').groupby('personal_id')
   ['creation_timestamp'].diff().dt.days
)

df['days_between_applications'] = df['application_id'].map(diff)
```

Output:

```
          personal_id application_id         creation_timestamp  days_between_applications
1007     c1de3552cfb0   e18e5d77199f 2019-05-16 06:53:57.817842                        NaN
1008     c1de3552cfb0   e18e5d77199f 2019-05-16 06:53:57.817842                        NaN
1010     c1de3552cfb0   e18e5d77199f 2019-05-16 06:53:57.817842                        NaN
1006     c1de3552cfb0   e18e5d77199f 2019-05-16 06:53:57.817842                        NaN
7094153  c1de3552cfb0   1f64dd61aee2 2023-08-07 11:01:45.588173                     1544.0
7094147  c1de3552cfb0   1f64dd61aee2 2023-08-07 11:01:45.588173                     1544.0
```

Intermediate `diff`:

```
application_id
e18e5d77199f       NaN
1f64dd61aee2    1544.0
Name: creation_timestamp, dtype: float64
```

Variant if the `application_id` are not necessarily unique to one `personal_id`:

```
df['creation_timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['creation_timestamp'])

diff = (df
   .drop_duplicates(['personal_id', 'application_id'])
   .sort_values(by='creation_timestamp')
   .set_index(['application_id', 'personal_id']).groupby('personal_id')
   ['creation_timestamp'].diff().dt.days
)

df['days_between_applications'] = diff.reindex(df.set_index(['application_id', 'personal_id']).index).values
```